# Reading BigQuery Table Data in for of Java Classes(Pojo)

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I need to read the Table Data from Bigquery using dataflow but instead of using/storing data into TableRow Class. I want to Store Data in Java Pojo Classes, is there any method using that I directly map the data into Pojo.

Way2:

````
GenericRecord s = schemaAndRecord.getRecord();

            org.apache.avro.Schema s1 = s.getSchema();
            for (Field f : s1.getFields()) {
                counter++;      
                mapping.put(f.name(), null==s.get(f.name())?null:String.valueOf(s.get(counter)));
                if(f.name().equalsIgnoreCase("reason_code_id")) {
                    BigDecimal numericValue =
                            new Conversions.DecimalConversion()
                                .fromBytes((ByteBuffer)s.get(f.name()) , Schema.create(s1.getType()), s1.getLogicalType());
                    System.out.println("Numeric Con"+numericValue);
                }
                else {
                        System.out.println("Else Condition "+f.name());
                }
            }
            ```

Facing Issue:

2019-05-24 (14:10:37) org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Can't create a: RECORD

StackTrace

java.io.IOException: Failed to start reading from source: gs://trusted-bucket/mgp/temp/BigQueryExtractTemp/3a5365f1e53d4dd393f0eda15a2c6bd4/000000000000.avro range [0, 65461)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$BoundedReaderIterator.start(WorkerCustomSources.java:596)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation$SynchronizedReaderIterator.start(ReadOperation.java:361)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:194)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.executeWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:411)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:380)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:306)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:135)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:115)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Can't create a: RECORD
    at org.apache.avro.Schema.create(Schema.java:120)
    at com.globalpay.WelcomeEmail.mapRecordToObject(WelcomeEmail.java:118)
    at com.globalpay.WelcomeEmail.access$0(WelcomeEmail.java:112)
    at com.globalpay.WelcomeEmail$1.apply(WelcomeEmail.java:54)
    at com.globalpay.WelcomeEmail$1.apply(WelcomeEmail.java:1)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySourceBase$1.apply(BigQuerySourceBase.java:221)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySourceBase$1.apply(BigQuerySourceBase.java:214)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.AvroSource$AvroBlock.readNextRecord(AvroSource.java:567)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.BlockBasedSource$BlockBasedReader.readNextRecord(BlockBasedSource.java:209)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource$FileBasedReader.advanceImpl(FileBasedSource.java:484)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource$FileBasedReader.startImpl(FileBasedSource.java:479)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.OffsetBasedSource$OffsetBasedReader.start(OffsetBasedSource.java:249)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$BoundedReaderIterator.start(WorkerCustomSources.java:593)
    ... 14 more
````

Answer (score 1):

[BigQueryIO#read(SerializableFunction)](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.12.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html#read-org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction-) allows one to use any of the Avro to POJO conversion libraries/functions that exist.

For example, I am using the code from this [blog post](https://karengryg.io/2018/08/25/avro-and-pojo-conversionstips-for-kafka-devs/):

```
private static <T> T mapRecordToObject(GenericRecord record, T object) {
  Assert.notNull(record, "record must not be null");
  Assert.notNull(object, "object must not be null");
  final Schema schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(object.getClass());

  Assert.isTrue(schema.getFields().equals(record.getSchema().getFields()), "Schema fields didn’t match");
  record.getSchema().getFields().forEach(d -> PropertyAccessorFactory.forDirectFieldAccess(object).setPropertyValue(d.name(), record.get(d.name()) == null ? record.get(d.name()) : record.get(d.name()).toString()));
  return object;
}

PCollection<MyType> data = pipeline.apply(
BigQueryIO
  .read(new SerializableFunction<SchemaAndRecord, MyType>() {
    public MyType apply(SchemaAndRecord schemaAndRecord) {
      return mapRecordToObject(schemaAndRecord.getRecord(), new MyType());
    }
  })
  .from("mydataset:mytable"));
```

The code from the blog post assumes that the avro schema was used to generate the POJO.

Comment: Hi @Lukasz I have used the above method but the issue is while reading numeric data type value from Big Query the numeric column resultant is java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16 cap=16], is there any way to deserialize the Numeric Datatype while mapping to My Type Class.

Comment: Can you provide the Avro schema that you get from BigQuery that represents the numeric type?

Comment: I tried it as Done in the blog post but found the same result for Numeric Data Type Value. The below Link might help you, I am trying from here to get some inputs but still, my Hands are Empty. 
 https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/55564672ca23c9938cfd5b9017046acb4ff5f560/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryAvroUtils.java#L299

Comment: If you know the type you are trying to bind to is a BigDecimal and the input schema type is a ByteBuffer, you could invoke the same logic you linked to: http://go/gh/apache/beam/blob/55564672ca23c9938cfd5b9017046acb4ff5f560/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryAvroUtils.java#L299 before setting the value on property.

Comment: the Reference link is not reachable:http://go/gh/apache/beam/blob/55564672ca23c9938cfd5b9017046acb4ff5f560/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryAvroUtils.java#L299

Comment: Sorry, try https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/55564672ca23c9938cfd5b9017046acb4ff5f560/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryAvroUtils.java#L299

Comment: I tried the Way 2 But getting Exception 2019-05-24 (14:10:37) org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Can't create a: RECORD. I have Updated The Question and provided the Way2 Implementation For Reference Please take a Look if i am missing something then let me know.

Comment: Can you provide more of the stack trace and an example schema that this fails for?

Comment: I have edited the Question and Added the stack trace details but for more details, you can use the below 2 jobids 1. 2019-06-02_07_22_53-1682006672321983235 and 2. 2019-06-02_07_04_50-17375103946794041526

Comment: It looks like your schema has complex types within it. The logic for mapping types from schema to an object only work for simple types (int, string, double, ...) https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/api/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.html#create(org.apache.avro.Schema.Type). Try skipping over all schema types which are of type RECORD at first. Then try updating the logic so that you recursively performing the mapping from RECORD to the type the field expects. You can see the field that is referenced by printing out d.name()